# How to POST a list of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm making my first simple project that uses relationships, a pretty simple checklist app.  I'm trying to save a ItemList with title, and it contains a collection of items (Item name and item qty) that I'm using a different model for.  When I try to post from my form, I get the following modelstate error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'BringIt.Models.Item' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
>   deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
>   interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. ↵Path
>   'item', line 1, position 46." Name

I've tried to change the types in my VM and models, but can't get past this error.  Here is my existing code:

Models:

```
namespace BringIt.Models {
    public class ItemList {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace BringIt.Models {
    public class Item {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ItemQty { get; set; }
        public string Person { get; set; }
        public ItemList ItemList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My VM

```
namespace BringIt.ViewModels {
    public class AddItemsVM {
        public Item item { get; set; }
        public ItemList itemList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Client Side Controller

```
 export class CreateItemListController {
        public itemList = null;
        public item;
        public items = [];


        public addNew() {
            var item = {};
            this.items.push(item);
        }


        public save() {
            this.itemListService.save(this.itemList, this.items).then(() => { this.$location.path('/') });
        }
        constructor(
            private itemListService: MyApp.Services.ItemListService,
            private $location: angular.ILocationService
        ) {
```

Server Side Controller

```
namespace BringIt.API
{
    public class ItemListController : ApiController {
        private IEFRepository _repo;
        public ItemListController(IEFRepository repo) {
            this._repo = repo;
        }
        public IHttpActionResult Post(AddItemsVM data) {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                return BadRequest(this.ModelState);
            }
            var itemList = data.itemList;
            var item = data.item;
            _repo.SaveItem(itemList, item);
            return Created("", itemList);
        }
    }
}
```

Repo

```
public void SaveItem(ItemList listToSave, Item items) {
            if (listToSave.Id == 0) {
                listToSave.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
                _db.ItemLists.Add(listToSave);
                _db.Items.Add(items);

                _db.SaveChanges();
            } else {
                var original = _db.ItemLists.Find(listToSave.Id);
                original.Title = listToSave.Title;
                original.EventDate = listToSave.EventDate;
                original.Items = listToSave.Items;
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

The client-side service
namespace MyApp.Services {

```
export class ItemListService {

private ItemListResource;

public save(itemList, items) {
    debugger;
    var data: any = {}
    data.itemList = itemList;
    data.item = items;

    return this.ItemListResource.save(data).$promise;
}

constructor($resource: angular.resource.IResourceService) {

    this.ItemListResource = $resource('/api/itemList/:id');
}
```

}

angular.module('MyApp').service('itemListService', ItemListService);

Thanks for all help.  I've been at this for too many hours and just can't crack it.

Comment: If you know its a deserialization problem you should probably post the html/javascript instead of the repo.  Your model binder cannot bind properly because for each property in the item you need a corresponding property in the json unless its unrequired

Comment: your controller action  is not taking in any parameters, where are you getting the this.itemList etc`public save() {
            this.itemListService.save(this.itemList, this.items).then(() => { this.$location.path('/') });
        }`

Comment: using jackson javascript will make your life easier. It is built for this kind of situation.

Comment: thanks for looking, I've now added th HTML

Comment: I've also added the server side controller and shown the full client side controller.

Comment: I'm guessing I have a type problem with the collection,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the client you'll be sending a JSON message like:

```
{
   "itemList": {},
   "item": [{blah}, {blah}... ]
}
```

where `item` is a JSON array.

Your C# view model doesn't have an enumerable `item` property. The deserializer cannot assign an array of items to non-enumerable property. The error message you receive is accurate, but a little confusing if you're not used to the terminology!

I might recommend you remove some of the DB code from the question, because that's a different matter entirely.